# Get top 5 posts viewed using post_views_count

Tags: wp-query

I tried to get top 5 viewed posts and its not showing anything. What is wrong with the below code ?

```
remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');
$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => array('news'),
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'posts_per_page'=>5,
    'meta_key'      => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'         => 'DESC'
);
$query3 = new wp_query( $args2 );
while( $my_query2->have_posts() ) {
    $query3->the_post();
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></li>
    <?php
}
$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query();
```

In functions file

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0";
    }
    return $count;
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count     = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    $ip        = str_replace("::","",$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $ip        = str_replace(".","_",$ip);
    $viewip    = get_post_meta( $postID, 'post_views_count'.$ip, true );
    if(!$viewip)
    {
        update_post_meta($postID, 'post_views_count'.$ip, 1);
        if($count==''){
            $count = 0;
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        }else{
            $count++;
            update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
        }
    }
}
```

And this code will support cache?

Comment: Why are you using this `remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');` at the top and at last why you are doing `$post = $orig_post;` ?

Comment: Hi @the_dramatist 

I use the remove_all_filters to make sure the previous filter is cleared. you think should i remove them? 

Do you have any idea why post_views_count doesn't work with this code?

Comment: do you have a custom posttype 'news'? how are you setting the custom field 'post_view_count'?

Comment: Yes i have 'news' and i tried to all post type and nothing work. I updated the question.

Comment: You're using both `$query2` and `$query3` variables in your `while` loop. Is that intentional? You might want to create more descriptive variable names.